# SQLzoo tutorial | GROUP BY and HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

I can't answer correctly the following question in the

> Show the years in which three prizes were given for Physics.

I've written the following script but it returns to be wrong.

```
SELECT yr, COUNT(subject) FROM nobel
WHERE subject = 'Physics'
GROUP BY yr
HAVING COUNT(subject) = 3
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that query. What results are you seeing and what were you expecting?

Comment: Hi Declan, unfortunately I can't see any results because of a bug in the SQLzoo website. The only thing I see is the 'sad' smile which tells the query is wrong. It's the ninth question you can find at this webpage: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_nobel_table_can_be_used_to_practice_more_SUM_and_COUNT_functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query looks correct, but I can't be sure without a link to the SqlZoo page.

Try

```
SELECT yr FROM nobel
WHERE subject = 'Physics'
GROUP BY yr
HAVING COUNT(subject) = 3
```

-- it might be finicky about the exact format of results that you are returning. It's only asking for year.

Comment: You are right! Apologies for wasting your time guys, but thank you a lot.